# Improve CNN model's accuracy for clasifying fruits - Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I need to classify cherry, strawberry, and tomato with 3600 training images and 900 testing images. However, my model performed poorly and overfitted. I tried weight_decay to avoid overfiting but the model gave error around shape not fitting. My training accuracy is 85% and my testing accuracy is 60%.

This is roughly my training data, they are all around 300x300 pixels

[image]

Transformation:

```
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomRotation(10),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.Resize(224),  
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(224),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
```

Model:

```
Batch_size = 100
epoch = 8
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(CNNmodel.parameters(), lr=0.001)

class ConvolutionalNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 3, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(54*54*16, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 3)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = F.relu(self.conv1(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X, 2, 2) #kernel size 2, stride 2, padding tbc
        X = F.relu(self.conv2(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X, 2, 2)
        X = X.view(-1, 54*54*16)
        X = F.relu(self.fc1(X))
        X = F.relu(self.fc2(X))
        X = self.fc3(X)
        return F.log_softmax(X, dim=1)
```

Comment: Sorry, it was just I calculated the accuracy wrong. The updated accuracy is 85% training set and 60% test set.

Comment: Just curious which loss function are you using on this training?

Comment: I used: criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() and optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(CNNmodel.parameters(), lr=0.001)

Comment: you should use Early stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most egregious mistake in your approach is that you are training a NN from scratch instead of fine-tuning a model already trained on ImageNet.

Check out https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll try those pre-trained models